# Find exact substring in string array using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, substring

I'm trying to see if an exact substring exists in a string array. It is returning true if the substring exists in the string but it will contains spelling errors.

EDIT:
For example if I am checking if '`Connecticut`' exists in the string array but it is spelled '`Connecticute`' it will still return true but I do not want it to. I want it to return false for     'Connecticute' and return true for 
    'Connecticut' only

Is there a way to do this using LINQ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] sample = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\samplefile.txt");
        /* Sample file containing data organised like
        Niall      Gleeson      123 Fake Street     UNIT 63     Connecticute     00703       USA      
         */

        string[] states = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\states.txt"); //Text file containing list of all US states
        foreach (string s in sample)
        {
            if (states.Any(s.Contains))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found State");
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find State");
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: Are you wondering if LINQ has the ability to perform automatic spell-checking? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: if there are alternate spellings, you would have to code in the alternatives you would consider to be "passes".  this could be done with basic string functions, or with regular expressions.

Comment: @JoakimSkoog I wanted to know if there was a way to return an exact match using .Contains. It appears there isn't. Would you know of a good way to return an exact match?

Comment: @user3394486 `Contains` returns **exact** match

Comment: if `Connecticue` should return true for `Connecticut`, then what about `Conecticu` and `Konnecticut`? Your matching rules are totally not clear

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Apologies I should have worded it clearer. It is currently returning true for 'Connecticute' but I do not want it to. I want it to return false. I want it to return true for 'Connecticut' only.

Comment: You want `Equals` then, not `Contains`!

Comment: @Jamiec I just tried that but it is returning 'Could not find substring' for every string in the array even though some of them are there.

Comment: [mcve] or it didnt happen.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks Jamie, I'll try out that and get back to you. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @Jamiec Does `Equal` match exact strings only? If string 1 contained "New York" and string 2 contained "New York" it would return true? But if string 2 instead contained "I live in New York" it would return false as it is not an exact match?

Comment: @user3394486 exactly. But look at some of the regex answers - they seem to be a better fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, I dont think `Equals` will work for me so as I want to check if the substring `Connecticut` exists exactly in the string `Niall      Gleeson      123 Fake Street     UNIT 63     Connecticute     00703` so id like it to return a false. I see some solutions below using regex, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\b` to match [word breaking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) characters (ie. white spaces, periods, start or end of string etc):

```
  var r = new Regex("\bConneticut\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  var m = r.Match("Conneticute");
  Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // false
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass in the values from a string array into `var r`? So instead of `var r = new Regex("\bConneticut\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` It would be something like `var r = new Regex("\bStringArrayValue\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` and it would go through each item in the string array to see if it exists in `var m`?

Comment: Can't you just loop through your string array, making the same regex comparison for each item?

Answer (score 6):

`String.Contains` returns true if one part of the string is anywhere within the string being matched.

Hence `"Conneticute".Contains("Conneticut")` will be true.

If you want exact matches, what you're looking for is `String.Equals`

```
...
if (states.Any(s.Equals))
...
```

Comment: But... he doesn't want `Conneticute` to match `Conneticut`...?

Comment: @MikeChamberlain and `"Conetticute".Equals("Connetticut")` will not yield true. MInd you, your solution of word boundaries is just a better idea.

Comment: Yeah, the question is a bit ambiguous - hard to know exactly what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `string.Contains`, which matches whether the string contains the sequence of letters, use a regular expression match, with whatever you consider to be appropriate. For example, this will match on word boundaries,

```
var x = new [] { "Connect", "Connecticute is a cute place", "Connecticut", "Connecticut is a nice place" };
x.Dump();
var p = new Regex(@"\bConnecticut\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
x.Where(s=>p.IsMatch(s)).Dump();
```

This will match "Connecticut" and "CConnecticut is a nice place" but not the other strings. Change the regex to suit your exact requirements.

(.Dump() is used in [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/), which can be used to experiment with this sort of thing )